# Next.js image og meta tag only showing for homepage url

Tags: image, hyperlink, next.js, meta-tags

I added meta tags to the layout head for my Next.js website. 
Here is what I added :

```
        <meta property="og:type" content="website" />
        <meta property="og:site_name" content="Bouge" key="ogsitename" />
        <meta
          property="og:url"
          content={url ? url : "https://bouge.app/"}
          key="ogurl"
        />
        <meta property="og:title" content={title} key="ogtitle" />
        <meta
          property="og:description"
          content="Un service qui te donne accès aux associations, studios privés, terrains publics et activités citoyennes."
          key="ogdesc"
        />
        <meta
          property="og:image"
          content="https://bouge.app/_next/bouge.png"
          key="ogimage"
        />
```

When I copy my homepage link, all the og meta tags info are perfectly showing however if I copy an other url from the website, the image is not showing. 
Others infos, like the description are showing. 
I don't understand why the image isn't working because it is in my layout. The code is the same for each page so if the description works for all pages why isn't it the case for the image ? 
The image is in my public file.
I first tried this code for my image :

```
content="/bouge.png"
```

but the image wasn't showing in my firefox extension og tags preview on localhost (but once in production the image showed, but only for the mainpage).

Comment: In a page where it doesn't work, if you inspect the page's source in your browser can you see the `og:image` meta tag there?

Comment: Yes I can see it and I see the image path. Exactly the same as the homepage which the image is showing.

Comment: its not working because `content` need absolute url but you are giving it relative url i.e., `/boung.png`

Comment: I encounter with same problem. It should be like that "content="/bouge.png"" but you need to pay attention to image size. Set image size ratio as "1200 x 630 (1.9:1)" and it  works correctly in all likelihood .